# Emberjs set select's value to a record

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a record bounded to a form. In the text input the right value appears, but not in the select. Here is a JsBin: http://jsbin.com/pexolude/87/edit

**template**

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <div class="well">
    {{#em-form model=model.person}}
        {{em-input property="name" label="Name" placeholder="Please enter first name."}}

        {{em-select
            label="Category"
            property="category"
            content=model.category
            optionValuePath="content.id"
            optionLabelPath="content.name"
            prompt="--select--"}}      
    {{/em-form}}


    </div>
  </script>
```

**the record**

```
var person = {
  "person":
  {"id":1,"name":"Joe","bio":"some tex","category":{id:"2","name":"Drama"}}
};
```

p.s. im using ember-forms but it inherits from ember's input, select etc.

Answer (score 1):

Like you can see here: [Ember Ember.select get selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818420/ember-ember-select-get-selected-value) you can add a `selectionBinding` attribute to your `em-select`.

That way you can save the selected value by hitting save or the way you like in your application.

**Example:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <div class="well">
    {{#em-form model=model.person}}
        {{em-input property="name" label="Name" placeholder="Please enter first name."}}

        {{em-select
            label="Category"
            property="category"
            content=model.category
            optionValuePath="content.id"
            optionLabelPath="content.name"
            selectionBinding="selectedCategory"
            prompt="--select--"}}      
    {{/em-form}}


    </div>
  </script>
```

In your controller:

```
selectedContentType: null,
  selectedCategory:null,

  actions: {
    save: function () {
      var selectedCategory = this.get('selectedCategory');
      console.log(selectedCategory);
      // do saving stuff here
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please read my question again; my problem is not the saving but to LOAD a record into the form. As i can see Ember-forms controls take the property's value and bind the model's property with the same name. in this case the input is bound to the model.person.name but em-select's value cant be bound to model.person.category bc it is an object. If model.person.category would be "2" instead of an object it would work.