# How to select element by id from hbs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a select tag added using ember.js using this line of code

```
{{view Ember.Select contentBinding = "content"}}
```

later I have a button which call a function in the same controller, I'm wondering how to get the selected option from this select tag.

Note: its id is "**ember240**".

Comment: Please provide more context.

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation I found that the best solution is to declare something like this in the controller:

```
selectedoption : null,
```

and then use selection binding like this

```
{{view Ember.Select contentBinding = "content"
       selectionBinding = selectedoption}}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818420/ember-ember-select-get-selected-value) for more information about this issue.

Comment: selectionBinding does not exist anymore (in 1.7 at least).
It's now called "value". See my answer for details :)

Answer (score 1):

The official way would be using the `value` property:

```
{{view Ember.Select
   content=programmers
   optionValuePath="content.id"
   optionLabelPath="content.firstName"
   value=currentProgrammerId}}
```

This will bind the selected value using `optionValuePath` to the property given in `value`. In this case, the property `currentProgrammerId` in your controller will be set to the `id` property of the selected programmer.

The elements will be rendered using the `firstName` property.

An example `programmers` array would look like this:

```
programmers: [
    {id: 1, firstName: "Pete"},
    {id: 2, firstName: "Julia"},
    {id: 8, firstName: "Jessy"},
    {id: 22, firstName: "Hank"},
]
```

Reference: [Ember.Select: The content property](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html#toc_the-content-property-array-of-objects)